# Why can I not connect to SQL Server using server name, but works with IP Address?

Tags: sql-server

So, I have two PC (PC-A and PC-B) that I've set up with Windows 7 and SQL Server 2012. I setup a port forwarding for PC-A so I can access it remotely.
I can connect to SQL Server on PC-A from PC-B (using SQL Server Management Studio) by entering the PC-A ip address, but unable to connect if I'm using the server name of SQL Server on the PC-A.

Any ideas to make it works?

Comment: Have you added the IP - domain/machine name pair to your hosts file?

Comment: Can you ping the PC-A by its name? If not, the problem comes from your DNS Server.

Comment: @shree.pat18 how to do that? any tutorial?

Comment: This should help: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file

Answer (score 0):

Try using tcp:[Server Name],1433
1433 is the default port numberused by sql server

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround to this problem. I install hamachi on both PCs, register them to a same hamachi network. And now I can connect using the server name.
Thanks all for the suggestions.

Comment: Why mess with Hamachi? Why not just fix your DNS issue properly?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'm really is a novice. And this workaround is the only easy way I can think of.